# Execution error in cmd when process created through Runtime Class

Tags: java, jsp, batch-file

I am making a web application for compiling and executing java code.I used JSP and apache server, I created a batch file at the server end which contains  javac and java commands and when i run it by using Runtime class,the code compiled successfully but in the next phase i got an Error

```
Error: Could not load or find main class Example
```

Example is class name

And, when i run the batch file manually it worked.

The code i used in JSP is:

```
       <%
   Runtime rt=Runtime.getRuntime();
// RuntimeExec rte=new RuntimeExec();
   Process pr;
   try
   {
     pr=rt.exec("cmd.exe /c start "+bfile);
     pr.waitFor();

   }
   catch(IOException ex)
   {
     System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
   }
   %>
```

Here bfile is the batch file in the "user.home".

The Example class is as follows:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
class Example
 {
   public static void main(String[]args)
   {
    System.out.println("Hello World Testing");
   }
 }
```

The bfile is :

```
<%
    File bfile = null;
   try{
   //flname = request.getParameter("filename");
   bfile=new File(homeDir+"/"+request.getParameter("filename")+".bat");
   FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(bfile);
   DataOutputStream dos=new DataOutputStream(fos);
   dos.writeBytes("C:"+"\n");
   dos.writeBytes("cd\\"+"\n");
   dos.writeBytes("cd "+fl.getParent()+" \n");
   dos.writeBytes("javac "+filename+"\n");
   dos.writeBytes("java "+request.getParameter("filename")+"\n");
   dos.writeBytes("pause \n");
   dos.writeBytes("exit \n");
   dos.close();
   fos.close();
    }
    catch(IOException ioe)
    {
        System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
    }
   %>
```

Comment: The error referes to a class Example, that is not used in the code you show. All I can say is that the error does not occurs in the part currently shown !

Comment: Well,I stored the Example class and batch file on server side,and I mentioned that when i run the batch manually it executed successfully.

Comment: The cmd opens within  tomcat directory and then goes to the batch file directory by cd commands.Is that causing the problem?

Comment: Unless you say what is class Example we can just try to guess (and my cristal ball is currently out of use)

Comment: i have attached the class Example.

Comment: is there any other approach for compiling and executing java besides cmd on windows plateform for my web app.

Comment: You should add messages in the batch file to see if it is actually started and (if it is) if the error occurs during the `javac` or `java` phase.

Comment: The  javac  phase executed successfully because the .class file created in the directory but at the java phase i got the  Error: Could not load or find main class Example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could (partially) reproduce. You try to start the execution of you class with :

```
java Example
```

This is correct only if your environment variable CLASSPATH contains `.` or does not exist. As you are starting your batch file from a JSP it should not.

So you must force classpath to `.` by using instead :

```
java -cp . Example
```